# How do I balance HVAC so my basement temp isn't so extreme?

Tags: hvac

I have a finished basement but there are no air returns in the basement. The basement is really hot in the winter and cold in the summer. The thermostat is upstairs on the wall and in order to get the house cool in the summer the basement is freezing, in order to get it warm in the winter it’s burning up in the basement. Will adding cold air returns in the basement fix this issue?

I have one in almost every room upstairs. It also keeps my heating bill higher then my 7 Kwh solar system can provide.

Comment: how many AC vents are there, blowing cold or hot air

Comment: partially close the vents in the basement.

Comment: You need the returns anyway. I'm surprised the system passed inspection without them. You need to answer the question from @Ruskes before you can get any real answers. The short answer is you have too much supply in both heating and cooling cycles. Look for dampers in the ducts and rebalance everything.

Comment: There are Six vents in the Basement and there are no return vents. the vents in the basement have been closed as much as I can. being that the basement is finished i will have to cut into the drywall to fix it. so I want to make sure i’m doing it right. so a have to patch as little as possible

Comment: If your system is providing *too much* winter heating or summer cooling to a zone, adding a return there will make it worse.  When you say the basement vents have been closed "as much as I can" .... do you mean they are fully closed?  So there is no air flow to or from the basement, and it is still receiving an excessive share of the heating and cooling?   That's odd, especially the heating part.  I think there is something missing from your description of the whole situation.

Comment: The summer situation can be explained more easily.  Cool air settling to the basement.  Let's focus on the winter.  Usually basements are cold and attics are hot.  If your basement is hot even though the vents are closed and there's no return ... you need to figure out how the heat is getting there.  There isn't enough info here for us to guess.

Comment: How about **a picture of your HVAC system *with no air sealing on it whatsoever* ?** There should either be (well adhered) foil tape or it look like someone painted the seams.

Comment: I had a utility room that got too hot; not very well sealed, had the HW *and* a washer and dryer in there. Everything except the dryer was power vented (**!** otherwise don't do this, if anything in there is gas fired and uses a natural draft flue, or there's no dedicated outside fresh air intake) so I cut a hole in the return chamber to add *a register* (so I could adjust it; not *a return grill*). - If it isn't that, **look for a damper that's closed to the upper floor.**

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume your heating/cooling appliance is located in the basement.

If you push air up to the top floor from the basement but there is no return to the basement then the appliance will have to fight to pressurize the top floor, I imagine air will leak outside, under doors and eventually back into the basement or outside.  If the air is pushed outside then your basement appliance will makeup the air - assume you have a vent that provides makeup air to your mechanical room. Your airflow to your top floor will take longer and be less efficient which could result in the basement reaching conditioned status way before either of the other floors.

Compare this to having a return where you push air into your top floor and the air can easily push existing air via the return to the basement appliance.  Ideally the full return path is sealed so that the unconditioned air doesn't displace conditioned air.

Comment: thank you for the comment and the advice. the returns are in the rooms and the kitchen in the main floor. there are no returns in the basement will this cause this make it hard to heat the main floor?